# $(window).width(); & $(window).height(); are coming out differently in every browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am relying on `$(window).width();` & `$(window).height();` for a resizing function and they seem to come out differently in different browser, same thing is also happening with `innerWidth/innerHeight`. What is the best way of getting an accurate value for this?

Thanks for any help
Thanks for inpt - for clarification I am using jquery Thanks but I am using 1.7.1 and I have the following css:

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;border:0;}
```

with no changes to padding or margin in html or body

Comment: You should clarify the question by pointing out which version of jQuery you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) clarifies that:

```
$(window).width(); // returns width of browser viewport
```

So being the viewport, each browser has a different viewport usable area.

Comment: You would have thought the usable area would mean no scrolling though - I am having to take 8px off width and height for ff and this is leaving me with an approx 8px gap in the width in IE9. I havent even got as far as seeing whats going on ine arlier browsers (dread!!!)

Answer (score 2):

$(window).width() is get the browser viewport width, why the ie browser get the less width? because in the left side of the browser, it has a border. so when you use the .width mothed, the ie browser's width will less than chrome\safari\firefox's.

Answer (score 1):

it is a old version jquery bug

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using `body, html {margin:0; padding:0;}` - might be default values in different browsers otherwise.

Comment: I have *{padding:0;margin:0;border:0;} am I correct in thinking that should cover body and html?

Comment: yep, this will cover everything - everything! If you try to use this selector in jQuery, you'll find it even matches <script> tags and such